# Hangman game error

Tags: java

i have written this code that is a hangman game
however the code keeps running when the user enters all the letters unless i write the word so it congrats the user.

i want it to stop when the user inputs all correct letters

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class question6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "testing";
        boolean[] strBoolean = new boolean[str.length()];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String test = "";
        int counter = 1;
        System.out.println("Java word guessing testing");

            // main for loop for guessing the letters
            while(true){
                System.out.println("Key in one word character or your guessed word:");
                test = input.nextLine();

                if(test.equals(str)){
                    System.out.println("Congratulation!");
                    break;
                }else{

                    // for loop for checking the boolean array
                    for(int b=0; b<strBoolean.length; b++){
                        if(str.charAt(b) == test.charAt(0)){
                            strBoolean[b] = true;
                        }                   
                    }

                    // for loop for printing the correct letters
                    System.out.print("Trail "+counter+": ");
                    for(int j=0; j<str.length(); j++){
                        if(strBoolean[j] == true){
                            System.out.print(str.charAt(j));
                        }else{
                            System.out.print("_");
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                    counter++;
                }
            }
    }

    }
```

Comment: You ask for a letter (or the solution) and then compare a letter to the whole word. How do you expect that to ever work for letters?

Comment: if (test.length() == 1){
     for(int b=0; b<strBoolean.length; b++){
      if(str.charAt(b) == test.charAt(0)){
       strBoolean[b] = true;
      }     
     }
     }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you are using attempting to compare your String `test` to the String `str`, but since you accept new user input for `test` before the you make that comparison, that conditional will only ever be true if the user types in "testing".  So make sure you keep track of the ordering in your instructions in the program for future cases.

You are keeping track of the user's progress by using an array of boolean values.  Thus, you could create a method that checks if all the values in said array are true, and return true if so.  See example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class question6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "testing";
        boolean[] strBoolean = new boolean[str.length()];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String test = "";
        int counter = 1;
        System.out.println("Java word guessing testing");

            // main for loop for guessing the letters
            while(true){
                if(allTrue(strBoolean)){
                    System.out.println("Congratulation!");
                    break;
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Key in one word character or your guessed word:");
                    test = input.nextLine();
                    // for loop for checking the boolean array
                    //and the rest of your code
                }
            }

    }
    public static boolean allTrue (boolean[] values) {
        for (int index = 0; index < values.length; index++) {
            if (!values[index]){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: i kept my code and called for the method at the end , because if i change order it wont accept if the user inputs the whole world

Comment: @nadhomshaker ok, if that is your requirement than use an or comparison in the `if` statement with test.equals(str) and the return of the allTrue method.  That should cover both cases then.  And if the answer helps you, be sure to accept it.